# Add/remove fxLayout and fxLayoutAlign properties conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to add/remove `fxLayout` and `fxLayoutAlign` properties conditionally in my div

```
<div *ngIf="name === 'A'" fxFlex="50%" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center"> 
...
</div>
```

Something like this does not work for me

```
fxLayoutAlign="myCondition? 'start center' : ''"
```

Any ideas what i can try?

Comment: Can We connect outside of this platform ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use like this..

```
[fxLayoutAlign]="someCondition ? 'start center' : ''"
```

Demo in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lacolaco-angular-flex-layout-example-jmgtwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)